# Swift - Set fixed spacing between cells that are diffrent widths in a CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collection view that is going to display user skills.

```
 lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(cvcSkills.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: self.skillsId)
        return collectionView
    }()
```

Each skill is in a cell that has a width set depending on the length of the word (as shown in the image)

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    var width:CGFloat = 0

        // Width size calculated depending on the size of the text
        let skill = skills[indexPath.row]
        if let name = skill.name {

            let size: CGSize = name.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)])
            width = size.width + 30
        }
    }
    return CGSize(width: width, height: 40)
}
```

[image: current view]

As you can see the spacing between these cells are arbitrary for some reason and i cant seem to get them to have an equal amount of distance from eachother.

I have tried setting insets like so(this is my current code which is displayed in the image):

```
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)
    layout.invalidateLayout()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

I have also tried setting `minimumInteritemSpacing` and `minimumLineSpacing` to diffrent values but i still keep getting diffrent size spaces between each of the cells.

Any idea on how i could get these cells to be spaced 10 away from eachothere.

Comment: “Minimum” being the operative word in those properties. This is how a UICollectionViewFlowLayout works as standard. If you’d like to change that then you should subclass it to create your own layout where you can define the spacing and size of cells as you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Fogmeister suggested, you need to create your own custom flow layout to support this need.

However, if you need, I have a flow layout that I have created that supports the above requirement, i.e., try `vertical` type (there are other types as well).

https://github.com/varunpm1/VPCollectionViewLayout

Although I shared it, I would recommend you to go through the code and try it yourself. Working with custom flow layout is fun.

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what i needed